# Inconsistent default site in the dropdown menu on the reputation leagues

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

When you go to the reputation leagues of a site, there is a drop-down menu that allows you to change quickly to another site. For example, on [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2020-10-01?sort=reputationchange):

[image]

and on [Super User](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/quarter/superuser/2020-10-01?sort=reputationchange):

[image]

So it seems that the default site on that drop-down menu is the site we are currently on. Makes sense. But if we now go to [Ask Different](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/quarter/apple/2020-10-01?sort=reputationchange), we see this:

[image]

Wait, why is Stack Overflow there as default site? But it gets even stranger if we go to [Board Games](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/147/quarter/boardgames/2020-10-01?sort=reputationchange):

[image]

or to [Spanish Language](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/353/quarter/spanish/2020-10-01?sort=reputationchange):

[image]

What does Biblical Hermeneutics have to do with Board Games? Or CiviCRM with Spanish Language? How is this "default site" chosen?

It is not like this breaks any functionality or hurts anyone. But it seems to be an inconsistency, and I am for sure interested in knowing the "pattern".